# LDAPPartial Date match in LDAP query

Tags: ldap-query

Is it possible to prepare LDAP query in which only Day and Month are considered by matching the Date.

Eg.

If Birth date is 28/09/1989 than in LDAP query should filter all the identities whose month is 09 and Day is 28.

thanks and regards,

Mayank

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer will depend on the attribute and its syntax.
If the birth date is a String, you could be matching based on substring:

```
(birthdate=28/09/*)
```

But this assumes all dates are exactly in the same string representation.

For data and time, the LDAP specifications only define a GeneralizedTime syntax and matching rule for equality.
However, there are some LDAP directory servers, such as OpenDJ, that have extended the matching rules and allow to match a GeneralizedTime with parts of it. However, not all servers support this.

Assuming birthdate is a GeneralizedTime with the following value `20010928000000Z`
You can query the server like this:

```
(birthDate:1.3.6.1.4.1.26027.1.4.7:=09M28D)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your reply. We have Active Directory LDS. The date is represented as 19941215000000.0Z , Value Type is string. But Still I am not able to search using (birthDate:1.3.6.1.4.1.26027.1.4.7:=09M28D) or (birthdate = 28/09/*)

Comment: A date as 19941215000000.0Z is a GeneralizedTime (represented as a string). But Active Directory LDS doesn't have support for those extended matching rules.  I don't think Active Directory LDS has any way of letting you search by partial dates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
The solution mentioned by you is not working for me. As soon as I place wildcards in query, search stops working.
Please find below more details about the attribute
Description : FT-BirthDate
Type : String
Numeric OID : 1.2.840.113556.1.6.1.1.26
Syntax OID : 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.24
Syntax Description : Generalized Time
I am using Apache Directory Studio to view above mentioned properties and to query the AD-LDS.
regards,
Mayank